# Sorting Id, date field on sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My present SQL Query is sorting by the date.  on 1/6/17 , I have two identical records with different id field.

Along with my `date desc` sorting, i want to include `id` field desc. So that the higher Id field value will come along with the recent date.

```
Id        Date  Status
0       1/6/17 8:40 Available
0       1/6/17 8:37 Available
0       1/6/17 8:37 Available
697000  1/6/17 8:37 Completed
700920  1/6/17 8:37 Completed
```

For some reasons, `Id` is not getting sorted. I tried `order by date, id desc`. `order by id desc`. it didnt work.

Comment: Please specify the output you want.

Comment: did you try `order by date desc, id desc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specify ascending or descending for each column in the `order by`. The default is ascending. `order by date desc, id` means `order by date desc, id asc`.

```
select id, [date], [status]
from tbl
order by [date] desc, id desc
```

If your `[date]` is a `varchar` column, you would need to [`cast()` or `convert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) it to `datetime` (or [other date and time data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)) to order by it properly.

```
select id, [date], [status]
from tbl
order by cast([date] as datetime) desc, id desc
```

Comment: @SqlZim, thank you so much. i didnt realize that i need to add desc keyword for every column as required. this helps a lot